# directory size in conky

Tags: debian, gnome3, disk-usage, non-root-user, conky

Conky is a system monitor software. I want to display the directory size of /usr and /var. Unfortunately I did not found any conky command so i made my own.

```
/usr $alignr${exec du -sch /usr | head -n1 | awk '{print $1}'}
/var $alignr${exec du -sch /var | head -n1 | awk '{print $1}'}
```

It works as expected for my /usr directory. The same command for the /var directory messes up my syslog:

```
#cat /var/log/syslog | tail -n 8
Oct 27 15:17:31 Hans gnome-session[1155]: du: das Verzeichnis „/tmp/systemd-private-3f1797004e2e4fceacc1baad91af9e67-cups.service-LhZ0Wi“ kann nicht gelesen werden: Keine Berechtigung
Oct 27 15:17:31 Hans gnome-session[1155]: du: das Verzeichnis „/tmp/pulse-PKdhtXMmr18n“ kann nicht gelesen werden: Keine Berechtigung
Oct 27 15:17:32 Hans gnome-session[1155]: du: das Verzeichnis „/tmp/.xrdp/xrdp-sesman-yqTUiU“ kann nicht gelesen werden: Keine Berechtigung
Oct 27 15:17:32 Hans gnome-session[1155]: du: das Verzeichnis „/tmp/.xrdp/xrdp-5M2L0E“ kann nicht gelesen werden: Keine Berechtigung
Oct 27 15:17:32 Hans gnome-session[1155]: du: das Verzeichnis „/tmp/systemd-private-3f1797004e2e4fceacc1baad91af9e67-colord.service-3EtIBW“ kann nicht gelesen werden: Keine Berechtigung
Oct 27 15:17:32 Hans gnome-session[1155]: du: das Verzeichnis „/tmp/systemd-private-3f1797004e2e4fceacc1baad91af9e67-rtkit-daemon.service-TgoTcd“ kann nicht gelesen werden: Keine Berechtigung
Oct 27 15:17:32 Hans gnome-session[1155]: du: das Verzeichnis „/tmp/systemd-private-3f1797004e2e4fceacc1baad91af9e67-cups.service-LhZ0Wi“ kann nicht gelesen werden: Keine Berechtigung
Oct 27 15:17:32 Hans gnome-session[1155]: du: das Verzeichnis „/tmp/pulse-PKdhtXMmr18n“ kann nicht gelesen werden: Keine Berechtigung
```

The Problem is that I need superuser rights to execude the du command. Is there another way to get the directory size of the /var directory without permission problems for no-root-users?

Debian 8.2(jessie) |
Linux 3.16.0 |
GNOME Shell 3.14.4 |
Conky 1.9.0

Comment: `du` is a fairly expensive operation. You shouldnt be running it every few seconds with conky.

Comment: You're better off using `df` for this effort than `du`. You won't need superuser permissions to run `df` since it (unlike `du`) doesn't need to `stat()` all the files and subdirectories within it's target (thus requiring permissions to read all those files, many of which shouldn't be read by normal users).

Comment: @John I was thinking the same, would just like to add that for this to work, mount /var on it's own fs, as df reports fs, not dir

Comment: possibly best - create lvm volume for /var and df that.

Comment: I (almost) always create a separate filesystem for `/var` anyway, so I'd assumed it was already it's own filesystem. IMO, you're asking for trouble if it's not it's own filesystem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can give your user the right to run `sudo du /var` with no password, I'll show you how later. However, do you *really* want this? There are very few files and subdirectories that `du` needs root access to. The difference is reported size between `sudo du /var` and `du /var` is tiny (at least on my system):

```
$ sudo du -s /var/
1830596 /var/
$  du -s /var/
1826040 /var/
```

Those both resolve to exactly the same number of gigabytes:

```
$ sudo du -hs /var
1.8G    /var
$ du -hs /var
1.8G /var
```

So, is such a small difference really worth it? It seems to me that a far simpler solution would be to just ignore the error messages by sending them to `/dev/null`:

```
/var $alignr${exec du -sh /var 2>/dev/null | awk '{print $1}'}
```

Note that I removed the `head` since that was only needed because you were using the `-c` option to print the total.

Since `du` is quite heavy and I doubt you really need this run every few seconds, you could also tell `conky` to only run the command once a minute:

```
/var $alignr${execi 60  du -sh /var 2>/dev/null | awk '{print $1}'}
```

---

If you feel that you really, really need the precise size of `/var`, run `sudo visudo` and add this line:

```
schmiddl ALL=NOPASSWD:/usr/bin/du -ch /var
```

Once you save the file, the user `schmiddl` will have the right to run `sudo du -ch /var` without a password, so you can add this to your `.conokyrc`:

```
/var $alignr${execi 60  sudo du -sh /var | awk '{print $1}'}
```